# Facebook SDK 3.0 - how to force AUTH dialog?

Tags: android, facebook

I am upgrading from Facebook Android SDK 2.0 to Facebook Android SDK 3.0 and I am looking for replacement for the following code:

```
facebook.authorize(activity, FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, facebookDialogListener);
```

So in Facebook Android SDK 2.0 there was a flag FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH that forced Facebook login dialog to show even if user had a valid Facebook session in Facebook app on a device. This flag is deprecated now and I haven't found hints on how I can replace it.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I know that this issue is connected to Single-Sign On (SSO) but disabling SSO is not an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, the answer is:

```
facebookOpenRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```